# How to change button colour after clicking another button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make my buttons change colour after clicking on another button. At the moment, I have an idea in mind... but that would be creating more html pages which is not what I want. The code below features 3 buttons where button1 is set as dark grey, and button2 and button3 are light grey. Clicking button2 or button3 should change to dark grey, and button1 should be light grey. I have tried researching on the internet and haven't found any solution to this.

Note: I have created my buttons using divs.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```css
 .select:hover {
   background-color: #2a2a2a;
 }
 .select:visited {
   background-color: pink;
 }
 .bcardunlaminated {
   display: table-cell;
   height: 37px;
   width: 210px;
   float: left;
   background-color: #2a2a2a;
   text-align: left;
   margin-top: 10px;
   line-height: 36px;
 }
 .bcardmatt {
   display: table-cell;
   height: 37px;
   width: 225px;
   float: left;
   background-color: #757575;
   text-align: left;
   margin-left: 3px;
   margin-top: 10px;
   line-height: 36px;
 }
 .bcardspotuv {
   display: table-cell;
   height: 37px;
   width: 230px;
   float: left;
   background-color: #757575;
   text-align: left;
   margin-left: 3px;
   margin-top: 10px;
   line-height: 17px;
 }
 .mat-font {
   color: white;
   font-size: 9pt;
   text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<div class="materialtable">
  <div class="materialrow">
    <a href="javascript:;" id=" hideaway1" onclick="document.getElementById('hideaway1').style.display='block';document.getElementById('hideaway2').style.display='none';
       document.getElementById('hideaway3').style.display='none';toggleTable();return false">
      <div class="bcardunlaminated select">
        <div class="mat-font">1</div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="javascript:;" id=" hideaway2" onclick="document.getElementById('hideaway1').style.display='none';document.getElementById('hideaway2').style.display='block'; 
       document.getElementById('hideaway3').style.display='none';toggleTable2();return false">
      <div class="bcardmatt select">
        <div class="mat-font">2</div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="javascript:;" id=" hideaway3" onclick="document.getElementById('hideaway1').style.display='none';document.getElementById('hideaway2').style.display='none';
       document.getElementById('hideaway3').style.display='block';toggleTable3();return false">
      <div class="bcardspotuv select">
        <div class="mat-font">3</div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="hideaway1" style="display:block;">1</div>
<div id="hideaway2" style="display:none;">2</div>
<div id="hideaway3" style="display:none;">3</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Inline JavaScript is bad practice and terrible to read.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Yeah I am aware of that, sorry :(. I will may make amendments to that if I have enough time at the end

Comment: Take 3 minutes and do it now.

Comment: @SW4: I've inherited enough crap code like that to want to vehemently discourage it. ;)

Comment: `window.onload=function() { var hideaways = document.querySelectorAll(".hideawayLink"); .... }` and IDs need to be unique!!! And please post toggleTable

Comment: @im1dermike - I agree, that and 20k line long JS files..

Comment: @mplungjan the toggletable() functions just displays different tables when a button is selected. It's not part of this question really.

Comment: @SW4: Dealing with pervasive inline styles now...

Comment: it might be since judging from the quality of the code so far, they are likely idebtical functions with tiny differences. Also wrapping divs in A is afaik invalid html

Comment: @mplungjan a tags are invalid to wrap around divs?! Think i'll update that part in future. Thanks for letting me know :)

Comment: @user3080993 its not invalid in HTML5.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a sample of what I think you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/f60z1nj3/2/

using jquery:

```
$(function () {
$('.test').click(function(){
            if ($(this).hasClass('darkGrey') ){
            $(this.children).removeClass('darkGrey')
        } 
        else
        {
            $(this.children).addClass('darkGrey');
            $(this).siblings().children().removeClass('darkGrey');
        }
    })
});
```

So I've just given your selectable items a class instead of an id, which is a bit less specific than using an id. Then its a simple onlclick event to add and remove a highlight class I've called darkGrey. I've not included toggling the divs at the bottom, as it looks like you have a function to handle that.

Comment: Thanks! Now I need to fiqure out how to put that on my page.

Comment: @mplungjan There's no inline stuff in my jsfiddle, nor invalid wrapping.

Comment: Actually it DOES have invalid html. It also does not work - it does not show div1 div2 or div3 when clicked and is running onload instead of head in the fiddle

Comment: @mplungjan Anchors with divs inside?

Comment: That will not validate.

Comment: @mplungjan I missed the duplicate Id's, but aside from that it validates fine for HTML5.

Comment: Right. HTML5 allows it if the divs do not contain clickable elements. In my book it stinks in any case

Comment: @mplungjan That's correct, but its the click event of the anchor I'm using here. I do agree with you, its not something I would do personally.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a change to the backgroundColor. I'm using orange here, use the one you want.

```
  <a href="javascript:;" id=" hideaway3" onclick="document.getElementById('hideaway1').style.display='none';document.getElementById('hideaway2').style.display='none';
                document.getElementById('hideaway3').style.display='block';document.getElementById('hideaway1').style.backgroundColor='#f60';toggleTable3();return false">
```

You HAVE to use unique IDs, you are using the same with an space in front, what makes it very confusing and buggy

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion - using jQuery since it seems you do not mind that based on your accepted answer:

You will need to change toggleTable to take an idx to toggle. You also likely want to make the container div of the links clickable instead of having the link. You will need to add a cursor:ponter to the CSS

```
$(function() {
  $(".select").on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // only needed if .select are links
    var idx = $.trim($(this).text());
    $(".hideaway").hide();
    $("#hideaway"+idx).show();
    toggleTable(idx);
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="materialtable">
  <div class="materialrow">
      <div class="bcardunlaminated select">
        <div class="mat-font">
          1
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bcardmatt select">
        <div class="mat-font">
          2
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bcardspotuv select">
        <div class="mat-font">
           3
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="hideaway1" class="hideaway">1</div>
<div id="hideaway2" class="hideaway">2</div>
<div id="hideaway3" class="hideaway">3</div>
```